# Model EC50/Kd values using ordinary differential equations

Tags: reaction-mechanism, kinetics, computational-chemistry, biochemistry, stoichiometry

It is my first attempt at using ordinary differential equations to model Kd for antibody binding and help will be much appreciated.

To provide some context, I possess binding curve data for the EC50 of various antibodies, each targeting different epitopes on our glycoprotein. Our goal is to explore the feasibility of employing luminex technologies to multiplex these antibodies on a single bead, thereby significantly enhancing the throughput of our assays. However, determining the correct stoichiometric ratios for each antibody is crucial, considering potential cross-reactions or agonistic effects due to varying affinities. For instance, a high-affinity antibody might influence the affinity of another, depending on factors that require a more extensive background explanation.

We have a suite on 12 antibodies and planning experiments with all possible combinations in a multiplex of three would necessitate around 1726 different experiments. To streamline this process, we are considering the use of ordinary differential equations to model these binding experiments. This approach aims to elucidate how the different antibodies, with their distinct Kd values, will interact when multiplexed.

Could someone kindly provide a comprehensive walkthrough of how they would approach this? Specifically, how do I incorporate the EC50 values (which are linear, thus EC50 = Kd) into the equations, and what order of ODEs should I employ for these equations? Being new to this, any insights and patience in guiding me through the process would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to write down the rate equations for binding in the simple case with no cross-reactions etc and solve numerically. But with cross -reactions you will need to know all these rate constants which I guess you don't know so you will have to guess them and keep on doing so until you can fit all the data simultaneously, by massive non-linear least squares fit. However, these rate constant values will probably not be unique. i.e. many values will fit the data, If this is important I can't tell.